# Making different image patterns appear in a silhouette shirt

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically im looking for suggestions on how to approach the idea of making a "shirt designer":

Imagine having a silhouette of a shirt.
Now imagine that I have 200+ fabric patterns for that shirt.

Clicking `$fabric_x` would fill the silhouette with that specific pattern.

Basically just like how its done here: (click fabrics to the left)
http://www.savvytailor.com/build-a-shirt.php?osCsid=c55610679180fcaa69abcae9b22dc0c5

*My idea*
... Which is the hard road to go, would be to:

- Save out a silhouette for each pattern filled from photoshop (loads of work)
- Administrate all the different fabric patterns in an XML list
- With Jquery -> load the XML > generate the list on frontend
- With Jquery -> create a function to replace/show the specificly clicked `$fabric_x`

Im thinking there would perhaps be some easier way to handle showing the $fabrics in the silhouette - besides having to save out an image for each silhouette-$fabric option.

Any ideas, comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be thinking to easy,
but couldn't you just lay a negativ form of a t-shirt(the shirt is transparent the rest white) image over a image of the pattern?

```
<img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/davorr/davorr1101/davorr110100011/8627355-pilze-seamless-pattern-swatch-muster-included-in-eps-datei.jpg" 
width="400" 
height="400" 
STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px" />
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62849616/Stackoverflow/shirts/hemd.gif" 
width="400" 
height="400" 
STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px" />
```

Take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vloxxity/m4APD/

Comment: Hi Vloxxity,

just trying to look at your fiddle suggestion to get the idea you're mentioning. But seems some image is similar is broken there?

Comment: The link to GIF is definitely broken.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now! - That could surely be an approach - and then work with a variaty of different shadow layers etc above that - guess though it all depends on how the patterns are setup to do that

Comment: ive updated the fiddle,
added a function to change the patern and style of the shirt.

Comment: HAy have you already checked my fiddle update?
Would you mind accepting the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks Vloxxity - I figured it out - you helped me on the way. Very nice fiddle example also, so awesome you took the time to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Your buddies over at http://www.savvytailor.com did exactly that: create a dozen of images per fabric type (cuffs, back, front, sleeves etc), then load necessary images based on user choice of fabric type. These files are distributed over a number of folders, one folder for each piece of shirt. File names corresponds to fabric types. So outside collar image for fabric coded PC04CP09-05 is located at http://www.savvytailor.com/3D_Shirt_Files/low-res-images/front-view/opened-collar/outside-collar/CL02/PC04CP09-05.png

If you use a smart folder structure, you don't need a separate XML to describe where is what, your PHP script will find it anyway.

You can obviously automate the file and folder generation process - using scripting functionality in Photoshop, or most popular 3d authoring tools.

Alternatively, you can load your shirt as 3d model using WebGL and just change textures.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for chipping in! Oh yes, I do indeed see a great amount of layers with differet shadowing etc - and did also think that with some Photoshop macro it could be somewhat automated. Perhaps that would be the way to go. My only thought was that I potentially just wanted to put all fabrics in one folder, and then some automated javascript/php script would take care of the rest (avoiding photoshop)